# QMake conditions don't work

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator, qmake

I created a project in which I would like to have different source files added to my project for different platforms. For that I used `conditions`:

```
QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = untitled16
TEMPLATE = app

MY_WIN_SOURCES = \
        file1.cpp \
        file2.cpp

MY_WIN_HEADERS = \
        file1.h \
        file2.h


MY_LINUX_SOURCES = \
        file1.cpp \
        file3.cpp

MY_LINUX_HEADERS = \
        file1.h \
        file3.h

FORMS    += mainwindow.ui

win32 {
    SOURCES = $$MY_WIN_SOURCES
    HEADERS = $$MY_WIN_HEADERS
    message("Windows...")
} else {
    SOURCES = $$MY_LINUX_SOURCES
    HEADERS = $$MY_LINUX_HEADERS
    message("Not Windows...")
}
```

But when I save the `*.pro` file, on `Windows` the project tree looks like this:

[image]

which is wrong because on Windows I shouldn't have `file3.h` and `file3.cpp` files:

Also `file3.h` and `file3.cpp` are also compiled and the shouldn't be compiled. Also the only message that appears after saving the `*.pro` file is `Windows...`

Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: So it works correctly on Linux then?

Comment: Please post the build log, I don't believe that `file3.h` and `file3.cpp` are actually compiled.

Comment: Ok, everybody, I'm stupid. The fact that @svlasov said he doesn't believe me made me think twice. What I was doing was I was including a `Linux` header inside a `Windows` header without guarding the include with `Q_OS_LINUX`, that's the reason it was compiling it...so my mistake. I got confused by the fact that the headers don't get hidden. So yea...everything works fine except the fact that I'm stupid,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is actually the feature of QtCreator. It shows you all of included files, regardless the conditions, but it should compile correctly.

You can read developer's list for more info: http://lists.qt-project.org/pipermail/qt-creator/2012-March/000419.html

> My understanding from earlier discussions is that this is intentional.
>   The theory is that you're interested in modifying the source files in
>   your project regardless of the build configuration you have chosen at
>   the moment.
>
> /s/ Adam

Comment: Yes, I got confused by that...I was accidentally including a `Linux` header in a `Windows` header without nay guards that's why I got compile errors...this cleared it out for me, thanks!